# Sql query to fetch single row into multiple items

Tags: sql

I want to fetch single row into multiple items.

For example my data is as below.

```
c1   c2
AA   1, 2, 3
BB   1, 2
```

I want to get the result as below:

```
C1  C2
AA  1
AA  2
AA  3
BB  1
BB  2
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: We need WAY more info - what RDBMS are you using?  How is this table structured?  What have you tried?

Comment: Use XML parsing or recursive CTE in SQL server. Use nested table in Oracle

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you please explain me with the help of example

Comment: @GurV Can you please explain me with the help of example

Comment: @joe which database are you using?

Comment: @GurV Actually the project fr which I am working in that we dont have accesss to db we store the values through UI and can retrieve it sql quiereies

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name isn't `string_agg` for combining rows into one?

Comment: @joe sql will execute somewhere? we need to know that *somewhere*. The answer depends on it

Comment: I will write the query in the .java file

Comment: **Again**: which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Since OP has no idea which RDBMS, I am gonna give the solution for two databases of my choice - SQL server and Oracle. :P

#### SQL Server:

```
with your_table(c1, c2) as (
  select 'AA', '1, 2, 3' union all
  select 'BB', '1, 2' 
)
select c1, a.q.value('.', 'varchar(100)') c2
from (select
    c1,
    cast('<q>' + replace(c2, ', ', '</q><q>') + '</q>' as XML) c2
from your_table)t
cross apply c2.nodes('/q') as a(q);
```

#### Oracle:

```
with your_table(c1, c2) as (
  select 'AA', '1, 2, 3' from dual union all
  select 'BB', '1, 2' from dual
)
select t.c1, x.column_value c2
from your_table t
cross join table(
    cast (
        multiset(
            select regexp_substr(t.c2, '[^, ]+', 1, level)
            from dual
            connect by level <= regexp_count(t.c2, ', ') + 1 
        ) as sys.odcivarchar2list
    )
) x;
```

Answer (score 1):

For Postgres:

```
select c1, t.c2
from the_table
  cross join lateral unnest(string_to_array(c2, ',')) as t(c2);
```